# Left Join query causing 'Column not found' error

Tags: database

In Drupal (v7.22) I'm trying to modify a query in a module so that it checks the value of an additional field from another table while looking for a result. I've been going through the documentation but cannot seem to stop my version causing an error. The original working code was:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, type FROM {node}
WHERE type IN (:type) AND LOWER(title) = LOWER(:title)",
array(':type' => $node_types, 'title' => $page_name,));
```

I've then added in a left join:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, type FROM {node} AS entity_id
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_test}
AS nid ON node.nid = field_data_field_test.entity_id
WHERE node.type IN (:type) AND LOWER(node.title) = LOWER(:title)
AND field_data_field_test.field_test_value = :test_value",
array(':type' => $node_types, 'title' => $page_name, 'test_value' => $tvalue,));
```

But it gives the error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'node.type' in 'where clause': ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes:

1. For complicated queries, use [`db_select()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7), not [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7). That way you will use enough of built-in failsafes to know what exactly went wrong.
2. If you insist on [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), or need an UNION or something [`db_select()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) simply cannot create, **never** use unbracketed full table name. That's why aliasing exists.

Your query should look about like that:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, type FROM {node} n
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_test} f
ON n.nid = f.entity_id
WHERE n.type IN (:type) AND LOWER(n.title) = LOWER(:title)
AND f.field_test_value = :test_value",
array(':type' => $node_types, 'title' => $page_name, 'test_value' => $tvalue,));
```